# High performance search on Django and select items? MySQL Database

Tags: django

I have a MySQL database and i have a Django model X with more than 1 million entries. I have to develop a web site where the user is able to search over 1 million items and select multiple items. I access these items through a ManyToMany relationship using Django forms with a MultipleChoiceField. But it's taking too much time when Django tries to load the 1 million items in a Django Form. How can i implement this efficiently in Django? The user should be able to search over the 1 million items efficiently and select multiple items.

I already tried using django-select2. This let me search, filter and select multiple items but it's still very slow.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of search: filter by PK/FK or fuzzy search based on user input? Have you checked appropriate indexes existence? `too much time when Django tries to load the 1 million items in a Django Form` you must avoid this.

Comment: You are right Ivan. I wanted to do fuzzy search based on user input. I'm now using Django Autocomplete Light. It works wonderfully. It doesn't load the 1 million entries but it uses pagination and filters by name :D Thank you so much